# ¿Cómo posicionar pestaña en un sitio especificó de página web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, diseño

Tengo una ventana modal y necesito posicionarla en la esquina superior derecha de la página.

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

Me gustaria que pareciera asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
  <div class="modalTipo" id="loginModal" >
      <div class="modal-content2">

          <div class="container" style="background-color:#d6d8da;">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4" ><label style="font-size:20px;color:#d6d8da;"> AfirmeNet </label>  </div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><label style="font-size:16px;color:green;background-color:#d6d8da">  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="rPersona"> Personas </label></div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><label style="font-size:16px;color:green;background-color:#d6d8da">  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="rEmpresa"> Empresas </label></div>
            </div>
          </div>


         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4"> <label style="font-size:20px;color:green;">   AfirmeNet </label>  </div>
              <div class="col-md-4"> <label style="font-size:20px;color:#BBBBBB;"> AfirmeNet </label> </div>
              <div class="col-md-4"> <label style="font-size:20px;color:#BBBBBB;"> AfirmeNet </label>  </div>
         </div>

         <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-4"> <label style="font-size:20px;color:#BBBBBB;"> AfirmeNet </label>  </div>
              <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#919292;color:white;width:auto;height:40px;" ><input type="text"  placeholder="USUARIO"  style="background-color:#919292;color:white;width:120px;border:0px;height:40px;" /></div>
              <div class="col-md-4" style="width:auto;height:15px;height:40px;" ><input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Ingresar" style="width:120px;height:40px;" /></div>
         </div>

      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.modalTipo {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.modal-content2 {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #BBBBBB;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 40%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    padding: 30px;
    opacity:0.9;
}
```

Comment: No se si eso debes hacerlo con un modal propiamente dicho o bien con un div fijo situado alli que lo escondas y muestres según convenga. Si quieres puedes poner clases del modal en ese div, pero si lo lanzas como tal no se si lo vas a conseguir. Por otra parte, si lo quieres fijar a una posición tan precisa, no se como se veria en dispositivos con resoluciones más bajas.  Ya se que no doy ninguna solución a tu problema, por eso simplemente aporto esto como un comentario.

Comment: Gracias masterguru... si tienes razon en tus indicaciones tambien pese igual...por  otros dispositivos no hay problema